# Android Wear 2.0 - Getting location from iPhone

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm developing an Android Wear 2.0 app and I'm paired to an iPhone. I'm using the FusedLocationProvider to fetch the location but I just can't seem to get the location.

Is this even possible?

If not, how can I know if I'm connected to an iPhone so that I fallback to the watch gps?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the [Location Data for Watches Paired to iPhones](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps.html#location-data-for-watches-paired-to-iphones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found what was happening.

We should indeed use FLP to get location when connected to an iPhone. Just make sure you allow access to location to Android Wear.

You can allow it following this:

- Settings > Privacy > Location services (must be On) > Android Wear > Allow location access Always